# Webfaction:: My site seems to be interrupted by other one, just showing "OK" text

Tags: dns, interrupt, webfaction, nameservers

My site usually works well but sometimes just show just simple "OK" text.

I don't know what is wrong.. and it seems very odd.

Webfaction and My site use Nginx as a server, but when my site is interrupted by the unknown one, the response header tells that it's from Apache Server.

Here is a response image..

Again Webfaction and I use Nginx not Apache Web Server.

I think this problem is attributed to Webfaction's other user who use Apache Webserver or.. 
... hm. I don't know..

Is there a someone who experienced the same problem as I have?

By the way, My Domain Registrar is Whois.com.

```
Request
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset:windows-949,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ko;q=0.6
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Cookie:fbm_144203575725136=base_domain=.tinysocialbox.com;     
    csrftoken=B2OS7jSswEyzpSvT7P4QjUSpILRK7RAk;fbsr_144203575725136=zpY1MFY19op74cxK2jhFAvjo61vxCPJh3AISbBbw9ec.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiIyLkFRQkI4N0lrbENFZWZXTk0uMzYwMC4xMzUwNjQ0NDAwLjEtMTAwMDA0MjEwMDkyMTMxfDEzNTA2NDA2ODB8NkFyZWFNcnlneUEyT3o5Zmp3REs5UmNSbVpZIiwiaXNzdWVkX2F0IjoxMzUwNjQwMzgwLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMTAwMDA0MjEwMDkyMTMxIn0; sessionid=b0268bc25c9db5c42d8935dd4669a233
    Host:tinysocialbox.com
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.92 Safari/537.4




Response
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Type:text/html
    Date:Fri, 19 Oct 2012 09:53:20 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=94
    Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

[image]

Comment: In addition, on my local computer, there is no such thing as Apache Web Server. It must be interrupted by something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using WebFaction's Nginx server, or did you install your own instance of it? What kind of application is it (PHP, Static, custom, etc)?

Your best bet is to open a support ticket here:

https://help.webfaction.com/

The support team can then check your application's configuration and figure out what is wrong.